# Overriding Modal Dialog from List Item Menu

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom edit form in SharePoint Designer 2010 and added it to the List Item Menu as my default edit page. It all works as expected except that, when the link is clicked, the page opens up in the modal dialog rather than "full screen" view. How can I force the link to bypass the modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under list Settings > Advanced settings > Dialogs, did you say no to "Launch forms in a dialog"?