# how to avoid open the modal dialog for new,edit & view form in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

Our end users want to show the new,edit & view form in another tab of the browser or within the same tab instead of working with modal dialog. Is there a possible to turn off this new behavior in SP 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps: [Overriding Modal Dialog from List Item Menu](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6490/overriding-modal-dialog-from-list-item-menu)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Its simple one, but I missed to see.